# Why am I getting "ImageView not initialized" error in GridView custom adapter?

Tags: android, android-gridview, baseadapter, android-adapter

I am making a custom `GridView` adapter which sets `FrameLayout` and its UI alements (images). The adapter itself is nothing complex, but yet I get compile-time error `Variable imgThumb have not been initialized`. What is worse, the code is exactly the same as on [Google Developer GridView help page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).

Here is my adapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private int mGroupId;
private Bitmap[] rescaledImages;
private Integer[] which;

public ImageAdapter(Context c, int groupId) {
    mContext = c;
    mGroupId = groupId;

    //.. do init of rescaledImages array
}

public int getCount() {
    return rescaledImages.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View frameLayout;
    ImageView imgThumb;

    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attribute

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        frameLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_grid_item, null);
        frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(130, 130));
        frameLayout.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);

        imgThumb = (ImageView) frameLayout.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_thumb);
    } else {
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) convertView;
    }

    imgThumb.setImageBitmap(rescaledImages[position]); //<-- ERRROR HERE!!!

    return frameLayout;
}
//...
```

Now, I know that I can set `ImageView imgThumb=null;` in `getView()` method, but I am not sure why this example works on Android developer help page.

Also I am not sure if I should put that `imgThumb` is ever `null`  - can this make a runtime error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it thanks to @LuckyMe (thou he did not reply the whole solution).

Anyway, for those who like me want to initialize and use root element of the `GridView` cell and its children, you should take care to **default initialize each child element as well** in the `else` by using `convertView.findViewById()` method.

Namely, my code must be fixed like this:

```
if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attribute

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    frameLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_grid_item, null);
    frameLayout.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(130, 130));
    frameLayout.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);

    imgThumb = (ImageView) frameLayout.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_thumb);
} 
else {
        frameLayout = (FrameLayout) convertView;
        imgThumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_thumb); //INITIALIZE EACH CHILD AS WELL LIKE THIS!!!
    }
```

Comment: To the bounds of the question, yes I did, I hope you return the respect.

Answer (score 1):

That code is NOT like the one you linked to, that code should crash even if you set `imgThumb = null`. Because in the case where `convertView != null`, `imgThumb` will never be set to anything, and therefore crash on the line `imgThumb.setImageBitmap(rescaledImages[position]);`.

Comment: Thanks. You lead me to the solution (upvoted). I posted the solution below as a reference to future people in same situation as myself

Comment: You are welcome, but technically that is the answer to your question, `Why am I getting “ImageView not initialized” error in GridiView custom adapter?` because of the whole in the code logic as explained.

Comment: Yes, but you should have warned me that I am not initializing gridview item properly :). That's why I said "you lead me to" the real problem. Funny thing is that Google always gives the simplest sample and I also did not find the way to deal with the multiple UI elements in the gridview item.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen only when your convertView is not null! So,you'll have to initialize imgThumb outside 'if' clause.

Comment: No, there is a better and proper solution. Look at my reply. In your case images will start appearing randomly while you scrollw gridview. TRy it.